# Why is the output not being printing?

Tags: c

This is a program to print armstrong numbers in a given range entered by the user, but when this program is executed and inputs are entered the outputs are not displayed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int low,high,sum,rem,orig_i;
    printf("enter lower and higher numbers : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&low,&high);
    sum=0;
    while(low<high)
    {
        for(int i=low+1;i<high;i++)
        {
            while(i!=0)
            {
                rem=i%10;
                orig_i=low+1;
                sum=sum+(rem*rem*rem);
                if(sum==orig_i)
                {
                    printf("%d",orig_i);
                }
                i=i/10;
             }
        }
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The output should be displayed when the program exits, but if the console windows closes then you will not have time to see it. The problem is that output to `stdout` (which is were `printf` writes) is *buffered*, more precisely *line buffered*. That means output won't actually be written until you print a newline. So please try to add some newlines to be able to see the output.

Comment: IOW: `printf("%d",orig_i);` -> `printf("%d\n",orig_i);`

Comment: You'll never exit the `while (low < high)` loop because you don't assign to `low` or `high` inside it

Answer (score 0):

As you are not increasing **low**, your loop is running infinitely and a few more errors too.
You can do like this. Although **there are a lot of efficient ways to write this programs** but i have done a little changes only to make it work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int low,high,sum,rem,orig_i;
    printf("enter lower and higher numbers : ");
    scanf("%d%d",&low,&high);
    while(low<high)
    {
        sum=0;
        orig_i = low+1;
        for(int i=orig_i;i!=0;i=i/10)
        {
                rem=i%10;
                sum=sum+(rem*rem*rem);
        }
        if(sum==orig_i)
            {
                printf("%d\n",orig_i);
            }
        low++;
     }
     return 0;
 }
```